# Send an e-mail when a new line is entered into Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is a list of RFIs from a client.  I want to be notified when a new questions is added to column F.  I found this code but I haven't been able to make the correct changes to get exactly what I need.  I have the trigger set to onEdit.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "me@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('F')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Ultimately what I need...  an e-mail sent only when a new question is added into column F or when an existing question in column F is changed.  The code above only sends an e-mail when I "run" from inside the script editor, and the e-mail contains data for the active cell rather than the new question in F or the edited question in F.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: You are likely encountering a trigger restriction: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/ .  Would the "Tools->Notification Rules" option in Google Sheets accomplish what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I only need a notification if a new question is added or if an existing question is changed; only a modification of Column F.  The sheet also contains a column for responses, so I think I would be inundated with e-mails whenever responses are added/changed.